# Initate Session on page load

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a requirement where I need to set Global Axios header and refresh session(Calling multiple Api's). In vuejs we would have a App.vue which is the entry point for our application we would do these types of processing in that.

**App.vue**

```
export default {
 async created(){
   await this.$store.dispatch('initateSession');
   }
}
```

The benefits of doing this is that this is called only once(not on every route change), and on every page load, I am looking to implement the same functionlity in Nuxt.

Now as we dont have any App.vue in case of Nuxt one solution that i could think off is to create a middleware for this , which can work but that will be called on every route change I dont want that, does anyone know any workaround for it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of middleware you can create a plugin:

`plugins/session.js`:

```js
window.onNuxtReady(() => {
  // Do something
})
```

And then add it to the plugins section inside `nuxt.config.js`.

Comment: I tried it , unfortunately the components are rendered before this,I want this to be the very first thing that runs before anything else is triggered is there a way to make it asynchronous?